# make the word go down with loops - dart programming languange

Tags: loops, dart

example i write a code like this :

```
main() {
  var input = 'i want to eat';
  print(input);
  var katas = input.split(' ');
  bool hurufHabis = false;
  var indexHuruf = 0;
  do {
    hurufHabis =false;
    var baris = 'Baris  ${(indexHuruf+1).toString().padLeft(2)} : ';
    for (var kata in katas) {
      if(indexHuruf < kata.length){
        baris += kata[indexHuruf] + '   ';
        hurufHabis = true;
      }else{
        baris +=   '    ';
      }
    }
    indexHuruf++;
    if(hurufHabis)  print(baris);
  } while (hurufHabis);
}
```

and the output will be like this:

```
i want to eat  
Baris   1 : i  w   t   e     
Baris   2 :    a   o   a     
Baris   3 :    n       t       
Baris   4 :    t
```

how can i change it to be like this :

```
i want to eat
Baris   1 :     w          
Baris   2 :     a      e    
Baris   3 :     n   t  a    
Baris   4 : i   t   o  t
```

i cant imagine the methode to be like that any help is appriciated. thank you

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be to padLeft the words to have all the same length:

```
var katas = input.split(' ');
var maxLength = katas.map((e) => e.length).reduce(max);
katas = katas.map((e) => e.padLeft(maxLength)).toList();
```

Comment: When i write this it says undefined name 'max',  what should i fill for max?

Comment: You need to import `dart:math`.